# Open terminal and launch commands

Tags: node.js, electron

In my electron/reactjs app, i'm trying to open a terminal and launch somes commands.

My code looks like this :

```
const terminal = 'x-terminal-emulator';
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn(terminal);
```

My terminal opens but i don't know how to launch commands in this terminal like 'cd /my/custom/path && ls'

Can someone help me please ? :)

Comment: You don't need any terminal to run commands. `spawn('ls /my/custom/path');`

Comment: This give me an error
`Uncaught Error: spawn ls /home/test ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
`

Comment: What i want is more like do 'xterm -e "echo hi;bash"'

Comment: That was my mistake. You need to pass arguments for the ls command in an array like this `spawn('ls', ['/my/custom/path]);` See the docs https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: Thanks, i don't have this error anymore, but how can put this command in a terminal ?

Comment: @laurentmichel Do you just want to execute commands? Or is it necessary that a terminal window is opened? This is an important distinction. Please update the question to reflect these aspects.

Comment: Hello, for my usage, i want to open a terminal window and launch commands (cd /my/path && nano mycustomfile.conf)

Answer (score -1):

Node.js `child_process.spawn` command have an [option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to specify the shell you want to use.

So I would use the opposite logic and launch directly the command within a particular shell (for exemple *bash*):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const terminal = '/bin/bash';

let cmd = 'echo $SHELL';

spawn(cmd, { shell: terminal })
  .stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);  //-> stdout: /bin/bash
});
```